# Create document from dotx template with classic asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp-classic

Is there a way to create document from dotx template with classic asp?

It is possible to create it on front end, or only on back end? I don't need the code, I just want to know the tool!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**SOLVED - Note:**

For those looking for java solution, consider this http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Persits ASPPDF - http://www.asppdf.com/

The only problem is that this kind of Tool can't run JavaScript, so you need to process everyting on back-end;

Comment: Ok, but this is the document generation, but I need something to the input (dotx template). Thank you, anyway.